# Unable to start rdebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdebug

I cannot seem to start rdebug on my machine.
Everything else seems to be working okay.
I've tried updating my gems without much luck.
I've tried some suggestion of setting the arch flag to x86_64 and update the gems. No luck again.
I am on a Mac OSX 10.6.6

```
/opt/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/linecache-0.43/lib/../lib/trace_nums.bundle: dlopen(/opt/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/linecache-0.43/lib/../lib/trace_nums.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)

/opt/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/linecache-0.43/lib/../lib/trace_nums.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper - /opt/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/linecache-0.43/lib/../lib/trace_nums.bundle
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: I had to reinstall ruby-debug and ruby-debug-ide to get them to be compiled and installed on Mac OSX 10.6.6. I probably installed ruby-debug before OSX upgrade to Snow Leopard. But this problem has been solved for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the linecache gem should fix this: `sudo gem install linecache`

If that doesn't cut it, it might have something to do with your gems coming from `/opt/` -- mine was failing on `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/linecache-0.43/lib/../lib/trace_nums.bundle` (and re-installing linecache fixed it).

Or you could work around it by running rdebug in i386 mode:
`arch -i386 rdebug ...`